# PHP $_POST value not appearing in email for PHPMailer

Tags: php, pdo, phpmailer

**Greetings everyone,**

I have a problem where the value for the student name and programme not appearing the email after I send the email through PHPMailer. I am using PHP PDO and I have checked that the student name and programme is under a form. Other values are appearing just fine in the email such as the image below:
[image]

I am not sure whether it is the quotation marks making problem or other things. 
Below are my code for the student-appointment-form.php file:

```
<?php
  require ("global-include-student.php");
  require ('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoLoad.php');
  require ('PHPMailer/smtp-credentials.php');

  //timezone for Malaysia
  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");

  //Condition when the submit button is clicked
  if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"])){
    try 
    {
      $appointment_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['appointment_date']));
      //$appointment_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

      // Inserting the data into database
      $insert_query = "INSERT INTO appointment (appointment_type, appointment_date, appointment_time, student_id, lecturer_id, field, venue, remarks, appointment_status)
                        VALUES ('".$_POST["appointment_type"]."',
                                '".$appointment_date."',
                                '".$_POST["appointment_time"]."',
                                '".$_POST["student_id"]."',
                                '".$_POST["lecturer_id"]."',
                                '".$_POST["field_id"]."',
                                '".$_POST["venue"]."',                 
                                '".$_POST["remarks"]."',
                                '".$_POST["appointment_status"]."'                                       
                                )";

      //PHPMailer set up
      $field_name = $_POST['field_name'];
      $lect_name = $_POST['lect_name'];
      $lect_email = $_POST['lect_email'];
      $student_name = $_POST['student_name'];
      $programme = $_POST['programme'];

      $output='<strong>Greetings from STULEC,</strong> <br/>
              <p>There is an appointment request from ' . $student_name . ' who is in the ' . $programme . ' programme.</p> 
              The appointment details are such as below: <br/>
                <ul>
                  <li>Appointment Type: '. $_POST['appointment_type'] .'</li>
                  <li>Appoinment Date: '. $_POST['appointment_date'] .'</li>
                  <li>Appointment Time: '. $_POST['appointment_time'] . '</li>
                  <li>Venue: '. $_POST['venue'] .' </li>
                  <li>Course Field: '. $_POST['field_name'] .' </li>
                  <li>Remarks: '. $_POST['remarks'] . '</li>
                </ul>
              </p>
              <p>Please approve the appointment request by logging into STULEC. Thank you.';

      $mail = new PHPMailer;
      $mail->isSMTP();                                // Set mailer to use SMTP
      $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';             // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
      $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                   // Enable SMTP authentication
      $mail->Username = EMAIL;              // SMTP username
      $mail->Password = PASS;               // SMTP password
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                    // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
      $mail->Port = 587;                        // TCP port to connect to

      $mail->setFrom('stulec@edu.my', 'STULEC');  //From sender
      $mail->addAddress($lect_email, $lect_name);  // Add a recipient
      $mail->isHTML(true);                    // Set email format to HTML

      $mail->Subject = 'STULEC | Appointment Request from Student';
      $mail->Body    =  $output;
      $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
      $mail->ContentType = 'text/html';                          

      if (($db->query($insert_query)) && $mail->send())
      {
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('An appointment has been made with the lecturer. Please wait until the lecturer responds to your request.');";
        echo 'window.location= "student-view-pending-appointment.php"';
        echo "</script>";
      }                                          
      else
      {
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: The appoinment cannot be made!');";
        echo 'window.location= "student-appointment-form.php"';
        echo "</script>";
      }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

?>   

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>STULEC | Appointment Form</title>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

 <!--Include header-->
 <?php include 'include/header.php' ?>

  <!--Include sidebar-->
  <?php include 'include/sidebar.php' ?>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1 align='center'>
        <u>Appointment Form</u>
      </h1>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="box box-default">
        <div class="box-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                  <!-- form start -->
                  <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST">
                  <?php
                     //select student details from the database
                    $sql = "SELECT username, name, role, department, programme, profile_pic, programme_name FROM users 
                    LEFT JOIN programme AS programme ON programme.programme_id = users.programme
                    WHERE user_id = :user_id";        

                    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                    if ($stmt->execute(array('user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'])))
                    {
                      while($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
                      {
                      //fetch the rows
                        $username = $row['username'];
                        $name = $row['name'];
                        $programme = $row['programme_name'];

                        echo " 
                        <!--Name-->
                        <div class='form-group'>
                          <label for='Name' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Name</label>
                          <div class='col-sm-10'>
                            <input type='text' class='form-control' name='student_name' id='student_name' value='". $row['name']."' disabled>
                            <input type='hidden' class='form-control' name='student_id' id='student_id' value=" . $row['username'] ." />
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--Programme-->
                        <div class='form-group'>
                          <label for='Programme' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Programme</label>
                          <div class='col-sm-10'>
                            <input type='text' class='form-control' name='programme' id='programme' value=" . $row['programme_name'] ." disabled>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        ";
                      }
                    }
                  ?>

                    <!--Consultation Type-->
                    <div class='form-group'>
                      <label for='ConsultationType' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Consultation Type</label>
                      <div class='col-sm-10'>
                        <select class='form-control' name='appointment_type'>
                          <option selected='selected' name='assignment_discussion' value='Assignment Discussion'>Assignment Discussion</option>
                          <option name='advisory_session' value='Advisory Session'>Advisory Session</option>
                          <option name='fyp_discuss' value='Final Year Project Discussion'>Final Year Project Discussion</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--Field name-->
                    <div class='form-group'>
                      <label for='Course' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Course Field</label>
                      <div class='col-sm-10'>
                        <select class='form-control' name='field_id' id='field_id' required>  
                          <option value=''>Please select a course field</option>         
                          <?php
                            //Display field name
                            $select_field_query = "SELECT field_id, field_name FROM course_field 
                                                    LEFT JOIN field_programme ON field_programme.field = course_field.field_id
                                                    LEFT JOIN users ON users.programme = field_programme.programme
                                                    LEFT JOIN programme ON programme.programme_id = field_programme.programme
                                                    WHERE field_programme.programme = :programme AND users.username = :student";
                            $field_statement = $db->prepare($select_field_query);
                            $field_statement->bindParam(':programme', $_SESSION['programme']);
                            $field_statement->bindParam(':student', $_SESSION['username']);
                            $field_statement->execute();

                            while ($row = $field_statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                            {
                              echo 
                              "<option value='" . $row['field_id'] . "'>" . $row['field_name'] . "</option>";
                            }
                          ?>   
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--Hidden course field_name-->
                    <input type='hidden' id='field_name' name='field_name'>

                    <!--Lecturer name selection-->
                    <div class='form-group'>
                      <label for='Lecturer' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Lecturer</label>
                      <div class='col-sm-10'>
                        <select class='form-control' name='lecturer_id' id='lecturer_id'>
                            <option>-</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>  
                    </div>

                    <!--Hidden lecturer email-->
                    <input type='hidden' id='lect_email' name='lect_email'>

                    <!--Hidden lecturer name-->
                    <input type='hidden' id='lect_name' name='lect_name'>        

                    <!-- Date -->
                    <div class='form-group'>
                      <label for='Date' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Date</label>
                      <div class='col-sm-4'>
                        <div class='input-group date'>
                          <input type='text' class='form-control pull-right' name='appointment_date' id='datepicker' required>
                          <div class='input-group-addon'>
                            <i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>
                          </div>
                        </div><!-- /.input group -->
                      </div><!-- /.form group -->    
                    </div>

                    <!-- Time -->
                    <div class='form-group'>
                      <label for='Time' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Time</label>
                      <div class='col-sm-4'>
                        <div class='input-group time'>
                          <input type='text' class='form-control timepicker' name='appointment_time' id='timepicker' required>
                          <div class='input-group-addon'>
                            <i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i>
                          </div>
                        </div><!-- /.input group -->
                      </div>
                    </div><!-- /.form group -->

                    <!--Venue-->
                    <div class='form-group'>
                      <label for='Venue' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Venue</label>
                      <div class='col-sm-10'>
                        <select class='form-control' name='venue'>
                          <option selected='selected' name='in_front_dpmt' value='In front of department'>In front of department</option>
                          <option name='library' value='Library'>Library</option>
                          <option name='consultation_room' value='Consultation Room'>Consultation Room</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--Remarks-->
                    <div class='form-group'>
                      <label for='Remarks' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Remarks</label>
                      <div class='col-sm-10'>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' name='remarks' id='remarks' placeholder='Eg: Related to the Local Area Network question' required>
                      </div>
                    </div> 

                    <!--Hidden Appointment Status which is set as Pending when form is submitted-->
                    <input type="hidden" value="Pending" name="appointment_status">

                    <!--Submit button-->
                    <div class="box-footer">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
                    </div> 
                  </form>
                </div><!-- /.box -->
            </div><!-- /.col -->
            </div><!-- /.col -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
      </div><!-- /.box -->

</div><!-- ./wrapper -->


<!-- Page script -->
<script>
  $(function () 
  {
    //Change lecturer when different course field is selected
    $("#field_id").change(function () {
      if ($('#field_id option:selected').val() != "")
      {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax-field-lecturer.php',
            data: { 'field_id' : $('#field_id option:selected').val() },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#lecturer_id').empty();
                var lect = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(lect, function( index, lectObj ) 
                {
                  if (index == 0)
                  {
                    $('#lect_email').val(lectObj.email);
                    $('#lect_name').val(lectObj.name);
                    $('#field_name').val(lectObj.field_name);
                  }
                    $('#lecturer_id').append("<option value='"+lectObj.username+"'>"+lectObj.name+"</option>");
                });
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
      }
      else
      {
        $('#lecturer_id').empty();
      }  
    });

    //Change lecturer email when different the lecturer is selected
    $("#lecturer_id").change(function () {
      if ($('#lecturer_id option:selected').val() != "")
      {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax-email-lecturer.php',
            data: { 'lecturer_id' : $('#lecturer_id option:selected').val() },
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(data);
                $('#lect_email').empty();

                var lect = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#lect_email').val(lect[0].email);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
      }
      else
      {
        $('#lect_email').empty();
      }  
    });

    //Show lecturer name
    $("#lecturer_id").change(function () {
      if ($('#lecturer_id option:selected').val() != "")
      {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax-name-lecturer.php',
            data: { 'lecturer_id' : $('#lecturer_id option:selected').val() },
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(data);
                $('#lect_name').empty();

                var lect = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#lect_name').val(lect[0].name);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
      }
      else
      {
        $('#lect_name').empty();
      }  
    });

    //Show course field name
    $("#field_id").change(function () {
      if ($('#field_id option:selected').val() != "")
      {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax-field-name.php',
            data: { 'field_id' : $('#field_id option:selected').val() },
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(data);
                $('#field_name').empty();

                var lect = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#field_name').val(lect[0].field_name);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
      }
      else
      {
        $('#field_name').empty();
      }  
    });

    //Date picker
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd"
    });

    //Timepicker
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({
      showInputs: false
    })
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please guide me on how to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: There is so much code. Can you limit to the **relevant** parts ?

Comment: By the way, your query is vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Consider using prepared statements.

Comment: var_Dump $_POST['programme'] and $_POST['student_name'] and tell us the result

Comment: @Cid : thanks for the advice. i will use prepared statements soon

Comment: @jameson2012: it came out NULL NULL as soon as i submitted the button

Comment: check R. Martin's answer below, he is right: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp .  You should also sanitise your inputs and use prepared statements as standard, not 'soon'.  You are also sometimes saving data to variables, sometimes accessing them directly, seemingly at random.  You should be checking post variables not just blindly assigning them to places, at the very lest a default would help guide you to the cause of your error e.g.  if you said $student_name = isset($_POST['student_name']) ? $_POST['student_name'] : "student"; - then at least you would have an output...

Comment: ... which would point you to the problem and also help you with searching for an answer, such as asking google 'why is my form field not set'

Comment: @jameson2012: thanks for the advice. i will keep that in mind. yes R. Martin's answer do work. It has solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your form your `student_name` and `programme` fileds are `disabled`, and not posted.
Consider using `hidden` inputs to post values or change `disable` to `readonly` (not sure if it the latter works tho).

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing out the problem. I have solved the problem by adding a input hidden for the student name and the programme